# Open a color picker in a html div without a scroll for the html div element

Tags: html, color-picker

I have a div, in that i am having  text boxes so when I click the text box the color picker is displayed. when I click a text box the color picker is displayed in the bottom..So what I need is the color picker should be displayed in the left or top without scroll....so can anybody help me....

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified any code or live sample the only thing I can suggest is to look at the color picker code. Most of them will have an extra parameter to specify the position [right | left | top | bottom ] of the picker.

Also the color picker element most probably a div will be absolutely positioned, so they won't affect your existing style. So there won't be any scrolling issue for the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCP2 = dhtmlXColorPickerInput('${p}_COLOR_CODE2');
        myCP2.setImagePath( pathIMG );
        myCP2.init();
        myCP2.setOnSelectHandler(function(color){
            var sId= ${p}_Grid.getSelectedRowId();
            ${p}_Grid.cells(sId,${p}_Grid.getColIndexById("COLOR_CODE2")).setValue(color);
        });
```

This is the code i am having.This code is displaying the color picker in the bottom....so what i need is the color picker should be displyed either in top r left...I tried putting setPosition(); but it didn't work.....so pls tel me wt to do